# Facebook Graph API class not found

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook graph api to get event information from a page.
I installed the Facebook SDK with composer but when I try to use a class in my controller it gives an error : Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found.

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET');

        $session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
        /* make the API call */
        $request = new FacebookRequest(
            $session,
            'GET',
            '/1531904510362357/'
        );
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

        dd($graphObject);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any autoloader mechanism in place? Otherwise, you will have to include the class files first. (FYI, the SDK ships with its own autoloader – embedding that file should take care of the rest if you do not use an autoloader already.)

Comment: Thanks that solved the error, but now I'm getting a blank page.

Comment: Then enable proper error_reporting/error logging, and make sure you catch possible exceptions where they might occur.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the Composer autoloader correctly.

You can see the instructions here https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Then make sure you are reporting on all errors. I would wrap my query in a try/catch block so you can catch any facebook exception as follows:

```
            try {
                    $query = (new FacebookRequest(
                                            $this->facebook, 'GET', '/me'
                                            ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className())
                    return $query;
            } catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
                    // The Graph API returned an error
                    return $e;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // Some other error occurred
                    return $e;
            }
```

Make sure to include the request exception class and graph user class too as follows:

```
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
```